# Display an additional element/ button everytime a button is clicked on the UI. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on React.js project. I'm a beginner. In the code below, I'm trying to create an additional button that displays "Hello World" every time it's clicked using setState. Can someone help me add to the DisplayMethod() function?

```
class MessageDisplayed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: "Hello World"};
    this.DisplayMessage = this.DisplayMessage.bind(this);
  }
  
  DisplayMessage() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      //How can I insert more "Hello World" buttons everytime it's clicked?"
    
    }))
  }
  
  render(){
    
    
    return (
      <button onClick={this.DisplayMessage}><h1>{this.state.message}</h1></button>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <MessageDisplayed />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the handler you can simply append "Hello World" to the previous state object of the functional state update.

```
DisplayMessage() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    message: state.message + "Hello World"
  }))
}
```

```js
class MessageDisplayed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message: "Hello World" };
    this.DisplayMessage = this.DisplayMessage.bind(this);
  }
  
  DisplayMessage() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      message: state.message + "Hello World"
    }))
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.DisplayMessage}><h1>{this.state.message}</h1></button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MessageDisplayed />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

With external message text

```js
const message = "Hello World";

class MessageDisplayed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message };
    this.DisplayMessage = this.DisplayMessage.bind(this);
  }
  
  DisplayMessage() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      message: state.message + message
    }))
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.DisplayMessage}><h1>{this.state.message}</h1></button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MessageDisplayed />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works. Why is it that when I declare a global variable, let anothermsg = "Hello World" and then on the DisplayMessage() function, change the code to --> message: state.message + anothermsg <--- it doesn't work>

Comment: @ShreejalLuitel That *should* work just fine. I updated answer to show.